# Division circuit - problem

Tags: circuits

I have a question about the logic circuit performing the division ( http://userpages.umbc.edu/~squire/cs313_l20.html ).

I implemented it to some software but does not work.

I drew the schematic circuit blocks of four CAS (2x2). Drawn circuit implements the division number of 3-bits by the number of 2-bits.

I'm interested only remainder.

The problem is that eg. for divident equal to 1 (binary 001) and the divisor equal to 2 (binary 10) getting the remainder equal to 3 (binary 11).

I attached a schemat of such a system with the selected values of all inputs and outputs obtained for blocks CAS.

I do not know where it can be a mistake, because there are elementary operations (XOR, FADD, NOT).

Can you hint where I was wrong?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: This is a non-restoring divider, which accepts two's complement numbers. "10" is -2, not +2. Your divider don't have enough bits.

Comment: @TEMLIB That looks like an answer, to me. Please post answers as answers, even if they're brief.